# Detect database changes

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'd like to be able to detect changes to the structure of the tables (not the data) in a SQL Server database. However, I don't know what I'm looking for exactly.

I don't need the exact changes nor do I need to be notified right away. I also only need changes to the table structure, not the actual data.

A simple thing like a `LastChangeDate` for each table that I could query from the database would be enough but I haven't seen anything like it.

**The why**:  We have a .NET application that copies rows while modifying some values to "bind" them to an other user. However, we've had troubles where someone would make changes to the database and the app would then be out of date. It is very risky to let users use that app if the database changes aren't reflected in the app. I want the app, upon opening, to check if the database structure changed since the last time it was opened and lock itself if it is so. Since the app isn't live, it can't be an event or trigger. I don't want to have to change much on the server as well (ex: turning on Change Tracking wouldn't be a viable option)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this could help. It just gets the table schema of the database and loads it in to a DataTable which you can in turn save to a file and then use as reference / compare.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using SQL = System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string DB_Name = "SomeDB" 

connectionString = "Server=" + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString() + 
                   "\\CUSQLEXPRESS;Database=" + 
                   DB_Name + ";Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

SQL_Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SQL_Connection.Open();

DataTable Project_Tables = SQL_Connection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

Comment: Ah, neat.  Love it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create DDL trigger to track all model changes with login names, dates, object name, modification statement and all other things you could need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx

> DDL triggers fire in response to a variety of Data Definition Language (DDL) events. These events primarily correspond to Transact-SQL statements that start with the keywords CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, DENY, REVOKE or UPDATE STATISTICS. Certain system stored procedures that perform DDL-like operations can also fire DDL triggers.

You can define only those events you need. You can avoid tracking of `CREATE USER` statements and so on if you don't need to:

> CREATE TRIGGER safety
>   ON DATABASE
>   FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE
>   AS
>      PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!'
>      ROLLBACK;

Make a table for loggin such events and look into it to determine whether any changes took place since last review.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended solution is to use [DB Migrations](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/) for *all* database structure modifications. As part of the modification you update an DB extended property:

```
EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty 
    @name = N'MyApplication DB Version', @value = '1.2';
go
```

Your app, upon connecting to the DB, first thing it checks this property and validates that it can work with the current version. If not, display a waning, urge the user to download the latest app version, and exit. The [Rails ecosystem](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) been doing this for year.

This works great *if every change is done via upgrades*. But it does not cover the problem of a rogue update that does not follow the procedure and breaks the app. For such cases my recommendation is to use DDL triggers or Event Notifications and monitor for updates. You would have to parse the [`EVENTDATA()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx) and update some table with details of the update, and have your app consult the table. Is doable, but I don't think is worth it. I would focus making the migration approach viable and keeping the updates disciplined (ie. modify the extended property).

As a side note, my company [DBHistory.com](http://DBHistory.com) specializes in monitoring such changes and you could get notifications when *any* change occurs, no matter *how* it occurs.

Comment: Would have been good but that would require a lot of changes to our database.  Was more looking for a quick and dirty solution.  Had it been a new project, that could have been great though.  Thanks.